# TFP and the residual with prodest() package in r

Tags: production-function, r

I am estimating a firm level production function in R and I am using the `prodest()` package, which is the equivalent of the prodest package in Stata, written by the same author, providing an empirical implementation of the estimation methods by [Ackerberg et al.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ECTA13408?casa_token=GVqcXNMpf2wAAAAA%3A_IUXqGZzwThL4GrEoDH6L9iqZSFRmTGsYLOXaRmK4dXOpJBePzBWNogKcTz3WWBOmwCwaOd7E-qhnJQ) (ACF) , [Levinshon and Petrin](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/70/2/317/1586773) (LP), and [Olley and Pakes](https://www.nber.org/papers/w3977) (OP).

The idea is that standard linear models used to estimate a production function yield incorrect estimates due to productivity shocks - that are unknown to the researcher but known to the firm - causing endogeneity and simultaneity issues when inputs of production are chosen, notably labour. Hence, each of the above methods come up with a two-step model to estimate correctly the coefficients on capital and labour thanks to a "workaround" that allows to identify the unobserved shock "omega". For instance ACF estimates what follows:

[image]

allowing for the identification of the coefficient on capital and labour and the inverted function, i.e. omega, in the second step:

[image]

Now I need to extract the residuals as a proxy of Total Factor Productivity. I am aware that one may argue that the omega term may be what we usually call TFP, but let's say that I need the residuals nevertheless. The question is: how should I obtain them?

The `prodest()` package allows for an extraction of `omega`as follows:
First the model is estimated

```
## df is some data
## what follows below can be replicated using the built-in data of the prodest() package 
## data(chilean)
lm1 <- lm(log_y ~ log_l + log_k, data = df)
acf1 <- prodestACF(Y= df$log_y, fX = df$log_l, 
                   sX = df$log_k, pX =df$log_int_inp, ##
                   theta =c(coef(lm1)[2], coef(lm1)[3]), ##starting points are needed
                   idvar= df$idvar, timevar = df$time, R= 30, opt= 'solnp')
## note ACF results vary too much according to starting point
```

Then you can obtain your `omega`. The point is that `omega`is actually equal to the residual, which should not be correct according to my understanding of the above papers:

```
omega <- omega(acf1)     
# is omega equal to the residual?                                             
res <- df$log_y- coef(acf1)[1]*df$log_l - coef(acf1)[2]*df$log_k
summary(omega)

> summary(omega)
       V1         
 Min.   :-14.279  
 1st Qu.:  1.901  
 Median :  2.390  
 Mean   :  2.300  
 3rd Qu.:  2.765  
 Max.   : 12.793  

summary(res)
> summary(res)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-14.279   1.901   2.390   2.300   2.765  12.793 

## yes, it is
```

Since `res` and `omega` give the same result, where has the standard residual gone?
If I try to get the residual treating omega as a part of fitted `log_y`, I  get a value equal to zero for almost all the observations

```
res_2 <- df$log_y- coef(acf1)[1]*df$log_l - coef(acf1)[2]*df$log_kt - omega(acf1) 
# this is virtually 0 for each observation
```

Because of the above, the only conclusion is that the `omega` term in `prodest()` includes the residual. Is this correct? Note that the package also allows to extract the first stage residuals:

```
 res_fs <- FSres(acf1)
 summary(res_fs)
> summary(res_fs)
 Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-16.45519  -0.25883   0.08109   0.00000   0.40840   6.49355 

## this behaves as you expect residual should do
```

However, if the residuals are correctly identified in the first step, this also means that the "true"  `omega` should be net of  `res_fs`

```
true_omega <- omega(acf1) - FSresiduals(acf1)
```

Any thougths on this? Am I correct on the "true" omega? What am I overlooking here?

I know there is a Stata equivalent but I do not currently have access to a Stata license, so I cannot test it. I am considering to write my own function but as the topic has been discussed on this sub in the past, I would like to get some feedback.